# Problemas al actualizar base de datos con java, Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: java

Buenas,

Tengo un programa en java que actualiza datos o inserta en datos en una tabla dentro de una base de datos. El programa funcionaba perfectamente hasta que hoy, en la tabla que tenía creada por defecto a través del programa de java, he agregado nuevas columnas para que las actualice manualmente. Al volver a ejecutar el programa me ha dado el siguiente error: `Field 'anywhere' doesn't have a default value`, que curiosamente es la primera columna nueva que he incluido. Lo que no entiendo es, ¿por qué tengo que definir un valor para la columna `anywhere`, al igual que supongo me pasará con el resto de columnas que he incluido manualmente, si en el programa de java no quiero actualizar esa columna? Os dejo el código:

```
public class Conectate {
    private String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/XboxOne";
    private String pass = "";
    private String usuario = "root";
    public Connection con;

    //public Conectate(Map<String,  Map<String, Item>> gamesByCountry, Map<String, String> codesByTitle,Map<String, String> countries) {
    public Conectate(ArrayList<Item> games, final Map<String, String> countries) {    

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion, usuario, pass);
            System.out.println("¡Conectado!");


            //CREAMOS LA TABLA
            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info_XboxOne (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), "
                    + "anywhere tinyint(1), black tinyint(1), black tinyint(1), fecha_spotlight TIMESTAMP, DWG tinyint(1), GWG tinyint(1),"
                    + "desde timestamp, hasta timestamp, juegos_vault tinyint(1),"
                    + "Juego_vinculado VARCHAR(500), Juego VARCHAR(500), Tipologia VARCHAR (500), Pertenece VARCHAR (500), "
                    + "Nota VARCHAR (10), Descripcion_Ingles TEXT(4000), Descripcion_Castellano TEXT(4000), Pegi VARCHAR(10), Pegi_USA VARCHAR (30) , Descripcion_Pegi VARCHAR(500), Codigo_juego VARCHAR (100),"
                    + "Lanzamiento VARCHAR (50), URL VARCHAR (400), URL_imagen VARCHAR (5000),"
                            + "Argentina VARCHAR (50), Argentina_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Argentina_Gold VARCHAR (50), Argentina_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Australia VARCHAR (50), Australia_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Australia_Gold VARCHAR (50), Australia_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Brasil VARCHAR (50), Brasil_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Brasil_Gold VARCHAR (50), Brasil_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Canada VARCHAR (50), Canada_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Canada_Gold VARCHAR (50), Canada_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Chile VARCHAR (50), Chile_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Chile_Gold VARCHAR (50), Chile_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "China VARCHAR (50), China_Oferta VARCHAR (50), China_Gold VARCHAR (50), China_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Colombia VARCHAR (50), Colombia_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Colombia_Gold VARCHAR (50), Colombia_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Espanya VARCHAR (50), Espanya_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Espanya_Gold VARCHAR (50), Espanya_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "USA VARCHAR (50), USA_Oferta VARCHAR (50), USA_Gold VARCHAR (50), USA_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Hong_Kong VARCHAR (50), Hong_Kong_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Hong_Kong_Gold VARCHAR (50), Hong_Kong_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Hungria VARCHAR (50), Hungria_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Hungria_Gold VARCHAR (50), Hungria_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "India VARCHAR (50), India_Oferta VARCHAR (50), India_Gold VARCHAR (50), India_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Inglaterra VARCHAR (50), Inglaterra_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Inglaterra_Gold VARCHAR (50), Inglaterra_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Japon VARCHAR (50), Japon_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Japon_Gold VARCHAR (50), Japon_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Korea VARCHAR (50), Korea_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Korea_Gold VARCHAR (50), Korea_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Mexico VARCHAR (50), Mexico_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Mexico_Gold VARCHAR (50), Mexico_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Rusia VARCHAR (50), Rusia_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Rusia_Gold VARCHAR (50), Rusia_Access VARCHAR (50),"                 
                            + "Singapur VARCHAR (50), Singapur_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Singapur_Gold VARCHAR (50), Singapur_Access VARCHAR (50),"                            
                            + "Sudafrica VARCHAR (50), Sudafrica_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Sudafrica_Gold VARCHAR (50), Sudafrica_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                            + "Taiwan VARCHAR (50), Taiwan_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Taiwan_Gold VARCHAR (50), Taiwan_Access VARCHAR (50)"

                    + ")");              

            System.out.println( "Tabla creada!");            

            for (Item game : games) {
                String titulo = game.getName();

                boolean isInsert;
                try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = ?")) {
                    ps.setString(1, titulo);

                    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                        isInsert = !rs.next();
                    }
                }

                if (isInsert) { //si se cumple esta condicción significa que el juego no está incluido, con lo que lo metemos
                    try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO info_XboxOne (Juego, Tipologia, Pertenece, "
                    + "Nota, Descripcion_Ingles, Descripcion_Castellano, Pegi,Pegi_USA, Descripcion_Pegi, Codigo_juego, URL, URL_imagen,"
                            + "Argentina, Argentina_Oferta, Argentina_Gold, Argentina_Access,"
                            + "Australia, Australia_Oferta, Australia_Gold, Australia_Access,"
                            + "Brasil, Brasil_Oferta, Brasil_Gold, Brasil_Access,"
                            + "Canada, Canada_Oferta, Canada_Gold, Canada_Access,"
                            + "Chile, Chile_Oferta, Chile_Gold, Chile_Access,"
                            + "China, China_Oferta, China_Gold, China_Access,"
                            + "Colombia, Colombia_Oferta, Colombia_Gold, Colombia_Access,"
                            + "Espanya, Espanya_Oferta, Espanya_Gold, Espanya_Access,"
                            + "USA, USA_Oferta, USA_Gold, USA_Access,"
                            + "Hong_Kong, Hong_Kong_Oferta, Hong_Kong_Gold, Hong_Kong_Access,"
                            + "Hungria, Hungria_Oferta, Hungria_Gold, Hungria_Access,"
                            + "India, India_Oferta, India_Gold, India_Access,"
                            + "Inglaterra, Inglaterra_Oferta, Inglaterra_Gold, Inglaterra_Access,"
                            + "Japon, Japon_Oferta, Japon_Gold, Japon_Access,"
                            + "Korea, Korea_Oferta, Korea_Gold, Korea_Access,"
                            + "Mexico, Mexico_Oferta, Mexico_Gold, Mexico_Access,"
                            + "Rusia, Rusia_Oferta, Rusia_Gold, Rusia_Access,"                 
                            + "Singapur, Singapur_Oferta, Singapur_Gold, Singapur_Access,"                            
                            + "Sudafrica, Sudafrica_Oferta, Sudafrica_Gold, Sudafrica_Access,"
                            + "Taiwan, Taiwan_Oferta, Taiwan_Gold, Taiwan_Access"                           
                    + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"                           
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ",?,?,?,?"
                            + ")")) {

                        ps.setString(1,titulo);
                        ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                        ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                        ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                        ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                        ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                        ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                        ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI_USA));
                        ps.setString(9,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));   
                        ps.setString(10,game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL)); 
                        ps.setString(11,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_JUEGO));
                        ps.setString(12,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_IMAGEN));
                        int contador = 13;
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: countries.entrySet()) {   
                            ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey()));
                            contador++;
                            ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_OFFER + " "+ e.getKey()));
                            contador++;
                            ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_GOLD + " "+ e.getKey()));
                            contador++;
                            ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_ACCESS + " "+ e.getKey()));
                            contador++;
                        }
                        ps.executeUpdate(); //aquí es donde me muestra el error Field 'anywhere' doesn't have a default value
                    }
                } else {
                    String query = "UPDATE info_XboxOne SET Tipologia = ?, Pertenece = ?, "
                    + "Nota = ?, Descripcion_Ingles = ?, Descripcion_Castellano = ?, "
                    + "Pegi = ?, Pegi_USA = ?, Descripcion_Pegi = ?, juego = ?, URL = ?, URL_imagen = ?,"
                            + "Argentina = ?, Argentina_Oferta = ?, Argentina_Gold = ?, Argentina_Access = ?,"
                            + "Australia = ?, Australia_Oferta = ?, Australia_Gold = ?, Australia_Access = ?,"
                            + "Brasil = ?, Brasil_Oferta = ?, Brasil_Gold = ?, Brasil_Access = ?,"
                            + "Canada = ?, Canada_Oferta = ?, Canada_Gold = ?, Canada_Access = ?,"
                            + "Chile = ?, Chile_Oferta = ?, Chile_Gold = ?, Chile_Access = ?,"
                            + "China = ?, China_Oferta = ?, China_Gold = ?, China_Access = ?,"
                            + "Colombia = ?, Colombia_Oferta = ?, Colombia_Gold = ?, Colombia_Access = ?,"
                            + "Espanya = ?, Espanya_Oferta = ?, Espanya_Gold = ?, Espanya_Access = ?,"
                            + "USA = ?, USA_Oferta = ?, USA_Gold = ?, USA_Access = ?,"
                            + "Hong_Kong = ?, Hong_Kong_Oferta = ?, Hong_Kong_Gold = ?, Hong_Kong_Access = ?,"
                            + "Hungria = ?, Hungria_Oferta = ?, Hungria_Gold = ?, Hungria_Access = ?,"
                            + "India = ?, India_Oferta = ?, India_Gold = ?, India_Access = ?,"
                            + "Inglaterra = ?, Inglaterra_Oferta = ?, Inglaterra_Gold = ?, Inglaterra_Access = ?,"
                            + "Japon = ?, Japon_Oferta = ?, Japon_Gold = ?, Japon_Access = ?,"
                            + "Korea = ?, Korea_Oferta = ?, Korea_Gold = ?, Korea_Access = ?,"
                            + "Mexico = ?, Mexico_Oferta = ?, Mexico_Gold = ?, Mexico_Access = ?,"
                            + "Rusia = ?, Rusia_Oferta = ?, Rusia_Gold = ?, Rusia_Access = ?,"                 
                            + "Singapur = ?, Singapur_Oferta = ?, Singapur_Gold = ?, Singapur_Access = ?,"                            
                            + "Sudafrica = ?, Sudafrica_Oferta = ?, Sudafrica_Gold = ?, Sudafrica_Access = ?,"
                            + "Taiwan = ?, Taiwan_Oferta = ?, Taiwan_Gold = ?, Taiwan_Access = ?"                           
                            + " WHERE Codigo_juego = ?";

                    try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
                        ps.setString(1,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                        ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                        ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                        ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                        ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                        ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                        ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI_USA));
                        ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));
                        ps.setString(9,titulo);
                        ps.setString(10,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_JUEGO));
                        ps.setString(11,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_IMAGEN));
                        ps.setString(92,game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL));
                        int contador = 12;
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: countries.entrySet()) {   
                            ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey()));
                            contador++;
                            ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_OFFER + " "+ e.getKey()));
                            contador++;
                            ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_GOLD + " "+ e.getKey()));
                            contador++;
                            ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_ACCESS + " "+ e.getKey()));
                            contador++;
                        }
                        ps.executeUpdate();
                    }
                }           
}


    } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    public String ConvertirObjectToString(Object Obj) {
    String Str="";
    if(Obj!=null){
        Str = Obj.toString();
    }
    return Str;
}


}
```

Lo he puesto en el código con un comentario, pero para que sea más sencillo de ver la línea que marca el error es la siguiente: `ps.executeUpdate();`

La estructura de la tabla, es la siguiente, aunque muestro las primeras columnas ya que son casi 100 en total:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También dejo todos los errores que me lanza:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que se me ocurre es definir también un valor para las nuevas columnas que he agregado, pero no entiendo por qué me solicita un valor cuando entiendo que no tengo porqué introducirlo con la ejecución del programa.

Comment: ¿Qué pretendes guardar en la columna `anywhere`? Ese error es de MySQL y es porque al hacer el update no le mandaste un valor para la columna `anywhere` ya que esta no tiene un valor por defecto y como son columnas nuevas que agregaste manualmente debes de darles un valor por defecto, o por lo menos permitirles valores nulos.

Comment: @Lixus es una columna booleana, los valores que tendrá serán o 1 o 0. De hecho de las 9 columnas que he incluido son todas o boleanas o timestamp. Ahora que comentas lo del valor nulo, puede que sea eso, puesto que la tabla al crearla desde java me la crea con el valor nulo activado. Voy a probar aunque tardará en darme el resultado.

Comment: Ok, si inténtalo, a mi me pasó lo mismo en un proyecto al agregar columnas nuevas una vez ya creada la tabla y no darles valores por defecto o permitir valores nulos para que los updates y/o nuevos registros no generen conflictos si no se envía nada a esas columnas en las sentencias

Comment: @Lixus Me sirvió tu respuesta, si quieres puedes responder para validar tu respuesta como la correcta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que veo es que no hay valor default para esas columnas y por eso te marca error.

por ejemplo:

```
 Antes:    anywhere tinyint(1)

 Despues: anywhere tinyint(1) default 0
```

No llene todos los campos porque no se cuales serian tus valores default en esas columnas.

Answer (score 1):

Te da error en la columna Anywhere porque es la primera que necesita un valor, ya que la columna *id* es `AUTO_INCREMENT` y no necesitas pasarle valor. Es decir, Como en la tabla no le has puesto ningún `default value` a *Anywhere* la base de datos espera un valor. Lo más lógico en mi opinión sería ponerle un `default value` a 0 o a 1 o insértale un valor:  `anywhere tinyint(1) default 0` .